# HTML5 - Write to a file with JS

Tags: javascript, html

So a friend of mine said they would help me with a problem if I could find out how to write to a file using JavaScript, the kind in HTML5.

JS and HTML5 aren't exacly my area of expertise, so here I am.
I haven't tried anything, other than a quick Google search.

Also, by writing to a file, I mean editing an existing text file on the client.

Comment: write to a file on the server (can do)? or on the client (can't do)?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work? I think we need more info on what you are trying to do. There is not a lot of detail on what you are trying to do.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Text File Editor</title>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="fileContent" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea><br>
  <button onclick="loadFile()">Load File</button>
  <button onclick="saveFile()">Save File</button>

  <script>
    function loadFile() {
      var fileInput = document.createElement('input');
      fileInput.type = 'file';
      fileInput.accept = '.txt';

      fileInput.onchange = function() {
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(event) {
          document.getElementById('fileContent').value = event.target.result;
        };

        reader.readAsText(file);
      };

      fileInput.click();
    }

    function saveFile() {
      var content = document.getElementById('fileContent').value;
      var blob = new Blob([content], {
        type: 'text/plain'
      });

      var a = document.createElement('a');
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      a.href = url;
      a.download = 'edited_file.txt';
      a.click();
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not good answers. How does this code solve the problem at hand?

Comment: @DarkBee there is a full comment above the "code only" i also said there is not enough info. So i provided what i could while reading between the lines. It allows the user to open the file and edit it just list he was wanting it too. (unless there is more he needs)

Comment: That comment doesn't explain the code at all...

Answer (score -2):

Certainly you can write to a file using js. Its pretty basic to implement.

To write to a file using js. You probably might have to install node.js to your computer if you don't already have one.

You can find an installation instruction from youtube. Search "How to install node.js and npm"

Afterwards,

you can write your code in a standard file as follows:-

```
// import the library to use the writing file capabilities in js
const fs = require('fs');

// Data to write to the file(Give the data you want to have inside the text file)

const data = 'Hello, world! This is redisnotblue';

// File path(Name of the file to want to create or could be existing file in the directory)
const filePath = 'redisnotblue.txt';

// Write to the file
fs.writeFile(filePath, data, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error writing to file:', err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Data written to file successfully!');
});
```

Run the file using the console

```
node nameofthefile.js
```

Let me know if you have any questions?

Comment: "*Its pretty basic to implement*" - How is setting up a full node server for this task *basic*? Furthermore the question isn't even tagged with node

Comment: I understand what you mean. But I never mentioned running a full stack node. The node comes pre installed with fs package. Thats all...Plus he needs to have the npm package handler installed for all basic tasks. From what I can understand, the person above is wanting to learn the basic setup to be able to practise in a js environment. He friend is asking him to learn it.